# Aggregate function with image data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

What is the best way to perform an aggregate function on an [`image`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.105).aspx) data type?

For example, where binImage is `image` data type, and I want to return either binImage or null:

```
max( case when somechar = 'A' and anotherchar = 'B' then binImage else null end ) as result
```

... will not work, because [`max`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx) does not support the image data type.

I know that [`image`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.105).aspx) is depreciated.

Comment: Are you using `MAX` arbitrarily to just get a single result?

Comment: @Nicarus well, not exactly "arbitrarily." `count` would not return the image, nor would `sum` or `min` or the like. But, yes I am trying to get a single result - thus the need for some sort of aggregate function here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image is really just a varbinary anyway so just cast it as such and then cast it back if you need to.  here is an example to show you that it works.

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (I IMAGE)

INSERT INTO @Table (I) VALUES (CAST('abcdefghi' AS IMAGE)),(CAST('abcdefghi' AS IMAGE)),(CAST('abcdefghi' AS IMAGE))


SELECT CAST(MAX(CAST(I AS VARBINARY(MAX))) AS IMAGE) as Img
FROM
    @Table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
Mediums,
CAST([1] AS IMAGE) '1',
CAST([2] AS IMAGE) '2',
CAST([3] AS IMAGE) '3'
FROM
(
    SELECT
    m.Description 'Mediums',
    u.ID,
    CAST(d.ArtWorkPicture AS VARBINARY(MAX)) 'Picture'
    FROM CDD_OrderDetail d
    INNER JOIN CDD_Mediums m ON d.MediumID = m.ID
    INNER JOIN CDD_UniqueUnits u ON d.UniqueUnitID = u.ID   
) tblTemp
PIVOT
(
  MAX(Picture)
  FOR ID in ([1],[2], [3])
) tblPIVOT;
```